# How do I convert for loop argument from Matlab to R?

Tags: r, matlab, for-loop

I have the following for loop argument in Matlab (not my code) :

```
    for phi=2*pi:-2*pi/RES:0
```

where

```
    RES = 360; % angular resolution
```

I am having trouble to think of a valid conversion to R code. Can you help me out in any way? Thank you !

EDIT: I was referring to the two intervals in the argument. I get the error message "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Comment: See `seq` function in R. In Matlab sequence is `from, by, to`. In R, `from, to, by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1)

```
for(phi in seq(from=2*pi, to=0, by=-2*pi/RES)){
   # elaboration here...
}
```

2)

```
for(i in RES:0){ 
   phi=i*2*pi/RES
   # elaboration here...
}
```

3)

```
for(phi in (RES:0)*(2*pi/RES) ){ 
   # elaboration here...
}
```

Personally, I prefer the second option since it's more readable (you immediately understand that you're looping `RES+1` times).